# Efficient method to scroll though pages using Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, scroll

I'm currently hard coding a scrolling using Selenium, Firefox Driver in Python, is there anyway for it to scroll smoothly up and down the page? The page can grow 20 times bigger than normal as the images in the page loads.

I need to scroll up and down multiple times , not missing out any part of the page.

The current method isnt efficient and sometimes doesnt scroll to some part of the page.
The following is my current code

```
 browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(link)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.4);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.5);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.7);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.8);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.2);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.3);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.5);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.7);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.9);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.2);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.1);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.8);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.7);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/50);")
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this if using Selenium in Python...

```
scheight = .1
while scheight < 9.9:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/%s);" % scheight)
    scheight += .01
```

Or something along those lines. You can add `if` brakes to capture data at specific `scheight` locations within the `while`. Just make the `+=` or iteration whatever you like. I used .01 so I could visually see it scroll, otherwise you would need timeouts and it would appear choppy. Depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to just do all the scrolling in one shot?

```
 browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.5);window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.7);")
```

Just list out all the scroll calls in the same execute script call.

Comment: He asked specifically to not do it this way. "is there anyway for it to scroll smoothly up and down the page?"

Answer (score 1):

Scroll directly to the given element (without pass the range of scroll).

Python code:

```
        from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

        element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=path)
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
        element.click()
```

Or for smoth effect use this:

```
        element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=path)
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});", element)
        element.click()
```

Comment: This is what worked for me:
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});", element)`

The `ActionChains` class did not do anything on the UI for me. I'm using Firefox driver. However, directly using `scrollIntoView` worked out. Thank you for this answer.