# Why does selenium not fetch all list items?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im am scraping profiles from LinkedIn sales navigator. All profiles are in a list item [image: inspect]

When I try to fetch all list items it only finds the first 10. What am I doing wrong?

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
names = sel.xpath('//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]')
len(names)
10

>>> print(names)
[<Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' 
data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, <Selector 
xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' data='<li 
class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, <Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 
pr6 
search-results__result-item"]' data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search- 
results__resul'>, <Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search- 
results__result-item"]' data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, 
<Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' 
data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, <Selector 
xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' data='<li 
class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, <Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 
pr6 
search-results__result-item"]' data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search- 
results__resul'>, <Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search- 
results__result-item"]' data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, 
<Selector xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' 
data='<li class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>, <Selector 
xpath='//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]' data='<li 
class="pv5 pr6 search-results__resul'>]
```

Comment: can you print the value of names to show what is stored in it? I think it will help understand the problem

Comment: @OsumanAAA I added it

Comment: can you elaborate on the "Selector" object you are using? I haven't seen it ever! do you mean Select()?

Comment: cant you use driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath here...") and iterate over the list.

Comment: @Infern0 when I do driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item"]'). I still only get 10 results.

Comment: can you paste the HTML sample here as a code ?

Comment: try using driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//li[contains(@class,'pv5 pr6 search-results__result-item')]");

Comment: @AshishKamble I still only get 10 results. I think it is because the page loads extra profiles while scrolling down. I now investigating how to fix this with selenium

Comment: @Codebeering you have to load all <li> first. You can click() on specific element to load more profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed selenium to scroll down to the page. I used this code:

```
 scheight = .1
  while scheight < 9.9:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/%s);" % 
      scheight)
      scheight += .01
```

Found the answer on this post: [Efficient method to scroll though pages using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803963/efficient-method-to-scroll-though-pages-using-selenium)